# Adding "div" and "input" using javascript with innerHTML function

Tags: javascript

I have written this javascript code

```
document.getElementById('placeForTitle').innerHTML=
"<div class='postAdLabelnTextboxSelTitle'>
       <div class='post-ad-label'>Select Title</div>
       <div class='selectTitleContain'>
           <input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_1' value='"+title1_1+"' required />
           <label for='tit1_1'>"+title1_1+"</label>
           <br />
           <input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_2' value='"+title1_2+"' required />
           <label for='tit1_2'>"+title1_2+"</label><
       /div>
</div>";
```

but it is not work and due to this other javascript function is also not working. I tried different combinations but not working.

Comment: document.getElementById('placeForTitle').innerHTML="<div class='postAdLabelnTextboxSelTitle'><div class='post-ad-label'>Select Title</div><div class='selectTitleContain'>
<input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_1' value='"+title1_1+"' required /><label for='tit1_1'>"+title1_1+"</label><br /><input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_2' value='"+title1_2+"' required /><label for='tit1_2'>"+title1_2+"</label></div></div>";

Comment: above code i m trying.. but not working

Comment: Pasting code in a comment isn't helping us much. Could you edit your question instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('placeForTitle').innerHTML=
"<div class='postAdLabelnTextboxSelTitle'>\
       <div class='post-ad-label'>Select Title</div>\
       <div class='selectTitleContain'>\
           <input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_1' value='"+title1_1+"' required />\
           <label for='tit1_1'>"+title1_1+"</label>\
           <br />\
           <input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_2' value='"+title1_2+"' required />\
           <label for='tit1_2'>"+title1_2+"</label>\
       </div>\
</div>";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('placeForTitle').innerHTML=
"<div class='postAdLabelnTextboxSelTitle'>" +
       "<div class='post-ad-label'>Select Title</div>" +
       "<div class='selectTitleContain'>" +
           "<input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_1' value='"+title1_1+"' required />" +
           "<label for='tit1_1'>"+title1_1+"</label>" +
           "<br />" +
           "<input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_2' value='"+title1_2+"' required />" +
           "<label for='tit1_2'>"+title1_2+"</label>" +
       "</div>" +
"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a new line in the middle of a JavaScript string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('placeForTitle').innerHTML="<div class='postAdLabelnTextboxSelTitle'>"
       +"<div class='post-ad-label'>Select Title</div>"
       +"<div class='selectTitleContain'>"
           +"<input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_1' value='"+title1_1+"' required />"
           +"<label for='tit1_1'>"+title1_1+"</label>"
           +"<br />"
           +"<input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_2' value='"+title1_2+"' required />"
           +"<label for='tit1_2'>"+title1_2+"</label></div>"
+"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById('placeForTitle').innerHTML=
"<div class='postAdLabelnTextboxSelTitle'><div class='post-ad-label'>Select Title</div><div class='selectTitleContain'><input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_1' value='"+title1_1+"' required /><label for='tit1_1'>"+title1_1+"</label><br /><input name='selctedTitle' type='radio' id='tit1_2' value='"+title1_2+"' required /><label for='tit1_2'>"+title1_2+"</label></div></div>";
```

you should not break the innerHTML content.